# Boto - how to delete a spot request given a request id

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto

I make a spot request using the below:

```
req = conn_spot.request_spot_instances(price=self.spot_price,instance_type=self.instance_type, ebs_optimized=self.ebs_optimized,image_id=self.ami,placement=self.zone,key_name=self.keypair,security_groups=[self.security_group])
```

I am able to get the spot request ID using the below:

```
request_id = req[0].id
```

I can check on the status of my request id usng the below:

```
reqs = conn_spot.get_all_spot_instance_requests()
```

Now...given the request_id I need to cancel the order e.g. if taking too long.  How do I do that using boto given the request id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cancel_spot_instance_requests(request_ids, dry_run=False)
```

See: [boto documentation](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/ec2.html#boto.ec2.connection.EC2Connection.cancel_spot_instance_requests)